# C++アプリケーションを別環境で起動できない

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

C++、Qt（たしか4.5くらいだったと思います）で開発したWindowsデスクトップアプリケーションを一度別環境（環境Aとします）にも移し、動くことを確認したのですが、さらに別のマシン3台（環境B、C、Dとします）ほどで確認したところ起動できませんでした。
開発環境も含めた環境については以下の通りです。

- 環境BだけWin11、それ以外はWin10
- すべて64bit、リビジョンもおそらくすべて21H2
- 環境AはQtなどは入れてはいないはずだが、C#、.NET Frameworkでの開発に使っている
- 環境B、Dではlibintl-8.dllがどの場所にもないことを確認（その他のマシンでは確認してません）

エラー内容としては「**libintl-8.dllが見つからないため、コードを実行できません。プログラムを再インストールすると、この問題が解決する可能性があります。**」というものです。環境Aでは各dllについてのこのエラーが出るたびに開発環境からdllを持ってきて、最終的に動くことを確認しました。
ただ、現在は1週間ほど開発環境と環境Aが確認できない状態なので、エラーが出ているdllを持ってこれません。そこで、dllダウンロードサイト（https://jp.dll-files.com/libintl-8.dll.html、https://jp.error-dll.info/file/libintl-8dll）からlibintl-8.dllをダウンロードしアプリケーション実行ディレクトリにおいて実行すると、「**アプリケーションを正しく起動できませんでした（0xc000007b）。[OK]をクリックしてアプリケーションを閉じてください。**」というエラーが出ます（"https://jp.error-dll.info/file/libintl-8dll"のdllはサンドボックス上で確認）。調べたところ64/32bitの不整合という話があり、確かにlibintl-8.dllがこれらのサイト上に上がっているものは32bitなのかもしれません。
数日のうちにこのエラーを解消してアプリケーションを起動できるようにしたいと考えています。何かアドバイスや不足情報等あればコメントいただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: jp.dll-files.com のファイルは説明で Architecture が "32" なので恐らく 32bit なのでしょう。あなた自身がビルドしたアプリが 32bit or 64bit どちらなのかを確認し、対応する DLL が必要になってくるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 今確認できないのですが、64/32bit両方で使えるようにプロジェクトを作ったつもりではあります。そうなるとexeや他のdllは基本64bit用になっていると認識しています。64bit用のlibintl-8.dllを手に入れる方法、あるいは手に入れなくてもアプリケーションを起動する方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 開発環境と環境Aが使えるようになるまで待てば良いのでは？ あるいは`libintl-8.dll`というのが何のためのDLLで動いている環境の何処から入手できるのか、もしくはソースコード等のプロジェクトが公開されているならそこへの紹介リンクを提示してみてください。 そうした情報が無いなら的確な助言や回答を得ることは難しいでしょう。

Comment: 事情があり数日のうちに解決したいと考えています。ソースコードは公開していません。。このdllの出元はもう少し調べてみます、ありがとうございます。

Comment: どうもMSYS2配下または単独のMinGW64/MinGW32のGetText/iConvあたりに含まれていそうですね。[diff can't load libintl-8.dll #2048](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/2048), [MinGW の make だけを手動でインストールする](https://amdkkj.blogspot.com/2017/08/manual-installation-of-mingw-make.html), [Vim/GVimのビルドと実行環境の作成](https://sites.google.com/site/fudist/Home/vim-nihongo-ban/mingwvim), [Package: libintl](https://packages.msys2.org/package/libintl) 単独でも存在するのかもしれませんが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。サンドボックス上ですがhttps://amdkkj.blogspot.com/2017/08/manual-installation-of-mingw-make.htmlを参考に、MinGWのインストーラマネージャーからめぼしいパッケージをすべて入れました。C:¥WINDOWS¥System32にlibintl-8.dllが入り、それを見に行っているようではありましたが、やはり0xc000007bエラーが出ます。あとはよく分からずregsvr32コマンドを叩いてみましたが、エラーになりました。

Comment: 7zipのコマンドでdllが64/32bitどちらか調べられるよう（https://pslabo.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/11/10/184109）で、入れてみたdllを軒並み調べてみましたがすべてx86でした。なので64bit用がどこかのパッケージにあるならやはり手に入れたいところではあります。。

Answer (score 1):

なんとなくDLLをコピーした場合、過不足がわかりませんし、バージョン不一致も発生しかねません。
別環境で動作させるためにあるべき姿としては、[Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html)を使用してインストーラーを作成するべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Qt Installer Frameworkは日本語の記事等も多くなく敬遠していましたが、一度勉強してみようと思います。（もし公式以外で分かりやすいドキュメントや記事をご存じであれば教えていただけると嬉しいです）

Answer (score 0):

DLLme.comというサイトからx64のdllがダウンロードできました。結局計4つのDllが足りないと言われ都度ダウンロードし、動くようになりましたが、出所がよくわからないものなので実稼働はやめておきます。ありがとうございました。